# Javascript - searching values in Table

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty now to programming, learning javascript at the moment. I have table, which has 754 values looking as this 000089/04/18/0601AX. I want to write script, which will return another table with values contain /04/18. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: The best way to actually learn a new subject is trying it out yourself. You should come up with a solution, and see if that works for you (I'd recommend using `"use strict";` in your code to have the JS engine complain on any errors), debug what you can, and if you are still stuck, you should ask a question on **your specific problem that defeats you**.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table is named myTable, and you can extract from it every item containing /04/18, like 000089/04/18/0601AX or 000104/04/18/0801DA and so 
but not 000089/04/17/0601AX or 000089/03/18/0601AX

The script would be:

```
function lookFor(myval, list){
    var values = []
    var key
    //iterate the table named list
    for ( key in list)
        {
        //check if value myval is included in actual item of the list
        if (list[key].includes(myval)){
        //if so push it in the new table
            values.push(list[key])
           }
        }
    //return the new table with looking value
  return values
}

var newTable
newTable =lookFor('/04/18', myTable);
```

all // lines ar comments you can erase them

lookFor(arg1, arg2) is a function with two arguments
arg1 is the value you want to check if is contained in a list
arg2 is the list in which you want to look

So with this function you can look for any value in a table